# Run and add unit tests to nodejs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, node-opcua

I want to run the tests related to this project on github, see folder test on https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua . Unfortunately I have no idea which testing framework was used and how to run all the tests?

Comment: Looks like mocha try "make test-cov"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, run `npm install`
This will install the required dependencies.

You can then use

`npm test`

See here:
https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/blob/master/package.json#L15

That will run the tests using Mocha.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. Unfortunately npm install trigger some errors on my machine and npm test won't run as well. Did you try it yourself?

Comment: please update your question with the resulting errors of npm install

Comment: I got it - the problem was, git was not installed!